# Jmeter Parameter CSV not recognizing variable

Tags: post, jmeter

I am confused on a Jmeter variable not getting picked up by the CSV Data config. I have a Thread with HTTP request, CSV Data Config, HTTP Header Manager, and Results Tree. Everything seems to work fine, but there is just one variable that is not recognized...

Here is the Request Body after running the test:

```
{  
    "W_ID": "${W_ID}",  
    "b": "b",  
    "c": "c",  
    "d": "d"  
}
```

For some reason the W_ID variable is not being recognized, but other variables are. All rows have the correct value assigned to them except the W_ID. I tried deleting the W_ID column from my file(in case there was weird formatting or white space), saving, and re-running the test, but same results.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help! Please let me know if I can provide more information or clarity.

Edit1:
I noticed that the object name shows up in the body of the service... could that have an impact? This is the body (inv_adj is the object name):

```
{  
  "inv_adj": {  
    "W_ID": "string",  
    "a": "string",  
    "b": "string",  
    "c": "string",  
}
```

Edit2:
CSV variables were requested:
Row 1: W_ID, b, c, d
Row 2: a, b, c, d

Comment: In the HTTP Request, here is the Body Data:
{
  "i_adj": {
    "W_ID": "${W_ID}",
    "a": "${a}",
    "b": "${b}",
    "c": "${c}",

Comment: Please post the variable names that you have given in your CSV data set config.

Comment: CSV variables added.

Answer (score 1):

In JMeter, If Variables are referenced as follows:

```
${VARIABLE}
```

> If an undefined function or variable is referenced, JMeter does not report/log an error - the reference is returned unchanged. For example, if UNDEF is not defined as a variable, then the value of ${UNDEF} is ${UNDEF}.

So, Double check your CSV Data Set Config that how you have defined your variable name for each row. Is it  `WarehouseID` or `W_ID` in your CSV data set config? If you use as `WarehouseID` in your CSV data set config, then you should use like `{"W_ID": "${WarehouseID}"}`in your HTTP Sampler's body.

**Edit:**

Here is an example step by step:

1. CSV Data Set:

[image]

2. CSV Data Set Config:

[image]

3. Request Body Before Test:

[image]

4. Request Body After Test in Results Tree:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made sure all of the variable names match within each area that they are declared. The CSV file has W_ID in Row A, Column 1. The HTTP request has "W_ID": "${W_ID}",

Comment: Could it have something to do with the object name being in the body? The body format has '{  
  "inv_adj": {  
    "W_ID": "string",  
    "a": "string",  
    "b": "string",  
    "c": "string"  
}'

Comment: Hi, I didn't find any problem with that. I've edited the answer with an example. Check it out if you have used like this or not. Thanks

Comment: The only thing that looks different is that you used Notepad and I used Excel. I still saved my file as .csv though, so I assume it is the same. Also your step 3 looks different than mine. I am using the HTTP Request... what did you use?

Comment: I've used Dummy Sampler for Debugging purpose. Are you facing it for only one variable? Did you check after changing your variable names? Did it occur every time (I mean after using .txt file)? I have also used `.csv` file and getting the expected result. Can you share your CSV Data Set Config? What did you mean Row2 for csv variables?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue locally on my JMeter instance. But I could not reproduce the error that you are facing. Unless we have your entire data file and the JMeter test plan, it is difficult to understand the issue. Please find below my test plan

[image: CSV data set config]

And then, look at the sampler configuration

[image]

When I replay this, I can see that the values are getting substituted properly.

[image]